# Stringify an array of HTML elements?

Tags: javascript

I have an array which has the follow HTML elements:

[image]

so how can i stringfy this object?
Hint: `JSON.Stringfy(myOb);` doesn't work .

Comment: Please show the result json you want. You can't just stringify whole elements.

Comment: What result do you expect to get?

Comment: It's not a JSON object, it's an array of HTML elements. You could try taking `outerHTML` on each element. If you don't know how to transform an array into an array of something else, or loop through the array, then you have some basics to learn before you tackle something like this.

Comment: I want this tags to be as string because i want to store it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can do

```
var html = '';
myObj.each(function(){html += this.outerHTML;});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must, try this:

```
JSON.stringify(myOb.map(function(elt) { return elt.outerHTML; }))
```

Comment: I got error: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Or there is way to incode this tags and then convert it to string